# I'm using EF in my application. I try to save\insert a new record to a Patient View

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-web-api

I made a view in SQL server and then added to to my edmx file in visual studio 2012  I then went to POST it on Postman and got this runtime error.

```
  Unable to update the EntitySet 'ViewPatient' because it has a DefiningQuery and no <InsertFunction> element exists in the <ModificationFunctionMapping> element to support the current operation.




//Controller action code   namespace MvcWebAPI.Models
  {
        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;

        public partial class ViewPatient
        {
            public int PatientID { get; set; }
            public int MedicationID { get; set; }
            public int GPID { get; set; }
            public string Firstname { get; set; }
            public string Surname { get; set; }
            public System.DateTime DOB { get; set; }
            public string Medication { get; set; }
            public string Alergies { get; set; }
            public string MedicationHistory { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Clearly. I made a view in SQL server and then added to to my edmx file in visual studio 2012 I then went to POST it on Postman and got this runtime error. How would I go about fixing it.

Comment: For future reference, you may want to ask your question in your submission. To answer your comment, try reading the message provided to you and debugging according to it:
`Unable to update the EntitySet 'ViewPatient' because it has a DefiningQuery and no <InsertFunction> element exists in the <ModificationFunctionMapping> element to support the current operation.`

Comment: I have asked it in my submission read the first line. I have read it I'm asking how to fix it.

Comment: There is no question in your original post, only statements. The error message clearly states exactly what is wrong and how to resolve the issue. If you cannot read error messages and make use of them in debugging, you need to get back to the 101's of development and start over.

Answer (score 0):

You need a primary key on the view. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/09/01/tip-34-how-to-work-with-updatable-views.aspx